# ErrorCode 180008 - Unable to queue Triggered Send request. There are no valid subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, rest, java, triggered-send

I'm trying to send an email by ET rest api in Java. 
I already successfully sent a SMS and got a token in response, but an error is triggered with emails.

Here is the JSON I send :

```
{
"To":
    {"ContactAttributes":
        {"SubscriberAttributes":
            {"FirstName":"West"}
        },
        "Address":"me@mail.com",
        "SubscriberKey":"me@mail.com"
    },
"OPTIONS":
    {"RequestType":"SYNC"}
}
```

And here is part of the response I get back :

```
"hasErrors": true,
  "messageErrors": [
    {
      "messageErrorCode": 180008,
      "messageErrorStatus": "Unable to queue Triggered Send request.  There are no valid subscribers."
    }
  ]
```

I believe I forgot to send some data but can you tell me what ?

BR,

Comment: You don't need to modify your title to indicate a question is answered. You just accept the answer that helps you most (as you have done). That makes it quite obvious anywhere else in the system the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you checked the option **Add subscribers to this list** under *Subscriber Management* when creating your triggered send.

To verify this option, go to *Email Studio > Interactions > Triggered Emails > Messages > Email > Triggered Sends* and navigate to your send definition and click on the name.

Furthermore this error can be returned if you didn't supply a field that is set to required/not nullable in the triggered send's data extension.

It is also possible that the email address is being blocked by ListDetective if you receive this error message. To check if this is the case you can try to manually add the subscriber via *Email Studio > Subscribers > All Subscribers > Properties > Add Subscriber > Manually* and check if you receive the error message *Your SPAM filter does not allow this email address and cannot be added.*. If that is the case, you need to contact support to identify the reason for blocking this email address (see [List Detective Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=List-Detective-Overview&type=1&language=en_US) and [List Detective FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268658&type=1&language=en_US) for more information).

**Additional Info:** Another reason I got this error was due to a bug in contact model which needed to be fixed by salesforce support, but shouldn't occur any more since one of the releases earlier this year.

Comment: Note: i got this error because I had a Data Extension field that held basically all of html body content/code of the email which was set to 1000 text chars, but i went over that, so I had to bump it up to 2000 chars

Answer (score 4):

Maybe will be useful for anyone in future.

I got this error in another case.

The triggered send was configured **only to Add Subscribers** to All Subscribers, **without Update checkbox**.

And the request to execute Triggered send was with existing SubscriberKey but with another email, not the one that is already stored in All Subscribers. So for this request I got message

```
     "messageErrors": [
         {
             "messageErrorCode": 180008,
             "messageErrorStatus": "Unable to queue Triggered Send request.  There are no valid subscribers."
         }
     ]
```

So the situation was that from one side we **cannot update** this subscriber with a new email as we don't have permission to update, and from another side - we **cannot add** a new subscriber as a subscriber with such SubscriberKey already exists and it must be identical.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!